# Using of boolean flag in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using below code, if i am sending "89" as pressure value and temperature as "Null" in this case it is showing "value not processed". I want it to show message of value processed and also for value not processed what condition i can use in below code.

```py
    payload = [{'id': 'Room1',
    'pressure': {'metadata': {}, 'type': 'Number', 'value': '89'},
    'temperature': {'metadata': {}, 'type': 'Number', 'value': 'Null'},`'type': 'RoomTest'}]`
    attrs = ['temperature', 'pressure']
    x = (len(payload))
    Flag=True
    for i in range(x):
        for j in attrs:
        y = payload[i][j]['value']
        if '' in y or 'Null' in y:
          Flag=False
     if Flag:
         print("successfully processed")
     else:
         print("successfully not processed")
```

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: `if '' in y` will always be true for any string

Comment: so how can id define empty string in python.Any help on this @CoryKramer

Answer (score 1):

I would skip both the flag and the explicit `for` loop, and use `any` instead.

```
if any(p[j]['value'] in ('', 'Null') for p in payload for j in attrs):
    print("successfully not processed")
else:
    print("successfully processed")
```

Comment: why we use any here?what is difference between both of them

Comment: `any` returns true if any of the boolean expressions produced by the generator are true. That's exactly what you are trying to do with your `for` loop, except you are using an explicit flag to remember when you found a matching condition. `any` basically sets (and returns) that flag for you.

Comment: Thanks @chepner , but for this also it is not sending value instead only shows "successfully not processed"

Comment: What value do you want? In your original, `y` just ends up being the last payload you check, `payload[-1]['pressure']['value']`.